# Changing header tag and link with Javascript image shuffle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following script to change a background photo upon refresh:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomImage = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var homePage = document.getElementById('homepage');

homePage.style.backgroundImage= 'url("http://sample.com/images/bg/'+randomImage+'.jpg")';
</script>
```

I need to change the associated description and link with each photo.  Here is the tag that needs to change:

```
<h3><a href="images/photographs/sample/sample.html">Description</a></h3>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, as I don't know how to address this.

Answer (score 0):

best using jQuery manipulating css property. Easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought for you to go by:

HTML:

```
<ul id="description">
  <li><a href="images/photographs/sample/stuff.html">description for img #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="images/photographs/sample/sample.html">description for img #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="images/photographs/sample/dude.html">description for img #3</a></li>
  <li><a href="images/photographs/sample/what.html">description for img #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#description li { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
var randomSeed = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var description = document.getElementById("description");
var homePage = document.getElementById('homepage');
homePage.style.backgroundImage= 'url("http://sample.com/images/bg/'+randomSeed+'.jpg")';
description.getElementsByTagName('li')[randomSeed-1].style.display = "block";
```

I basically hide everything up front and just display the relevant description.

The -1 is because the  array index starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, using jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        clickLink();
    });

    function clickLink(){
        $(document).on('click', '#link-image', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var bgs = ["http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/", "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2/", "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3/", "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/4/" ]
            var num = getRandomArbitrary();
            console.log(num);
            $('#homepage').css({"background":'url('+bgs[num]+')', border : "1px solid"});
            $(this).attr("href" , bgs[num]).text("Description Image " + num);
        });
    }

    function getRandomArbitrary() {
      return parseInt(Math.random() * 4);

}
```

[Here test in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johan_16/mqm8v/)

Comment: To be clear, this is associated with changing an image upon page refresh, not upon clicking the link.  There is an associated h3 tag and link that needs to change along with the picture.